# WSO2 ESB 6.1.0 Batch Processing

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a requirement to process 10 million records in MS SQL database using WSO2 ESB.

Input file can be XML or Flat file.
I have created a dataservice provided in WSO2 ESB.

Now, I start process to read from XML and insert into MS SQL database, I want to commit every 5000 records during processing via ESB so that if 5001 record fails, I can restart the processing from 5001 record instead of 0.

First problem, commit is happening for all records at once. I want to configure it in such a way that it should process 5000 records, commits in DB and then proceed with next set of records. Additionally, if the batch job fails after processing 10000 records, I want the batch job to start processing from 100001 record and not from 0

Please suggest ideas.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you running into problems?

Comment: First problem, commit is happening for all records at once. I want to configure it in such a way that it should process 5000 records, commits in DB and then proceed with next set of records.                                                                                           Additionally, if the batch job fails after processing 10000 records, I want the batch job to start processing from 100001 record and not from 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more or less common pattern. Create an agent/process continously reading from an ipc buffer (memory or file).
The ESB endpoint simply writes into the buffer.
The agent is reponsible of retrying and/or notify asynchonously if finally cannot commit.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can write start and end records in a file and place it in ESB, When the schedule starts it will pick the record from file, in your case 5000 and then process it in DSS, now if DSS response is successful  then you increment the record and update in the file in this case 10000, now if DSS response is not success then 10000 will be mentioned in the file, after you find the root cause as why it failed and fix it and then run the schedule then it will take record from 10000 and if it is success then write 15000 in file, so this will continue till it doesn't meet the end condition